# Установка и настройка video-js

Tags: node.js, javascript

http://videojs.com/

Очевидно, есть 2 варианта установки:

1) форкнуть с гитхаба, установить node.js, поверх grunt, сгенерить лист файлов.

**Проблема:** при работе с флеш-версией получаем из консоли "Uncaught ReferenceError: *V* is not defined"; сама версия подгружается, но не проигрывается

2) скачать с оффсайта пакет "для чайников".

**Проблема:** указанные способы переключить плеер по умолчанию на flash-режим вновь получаем ошибки в консоль и html5-версию.

Как лечить?

Comment: Для начала, покажите страницу (или код страницы). Без неё невозможно определить, где вы накосячили.

Comment: 1. http://timeart.platfor.ma/test/tvi-player/video-js/sandbox/index.html.example
2. http://timeart.platfor.ma/test/video-js/demo.html

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но вы неуместно используете слово "пруф" — бросается в глаза.